# Node js: Object pushes into an array before few object properties hasn't been returned from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to hit an api and setting data to an object properties. I am setting few properties inside javascript promise and then pushing object in array outside the promise. So now object pushed before values returned from promise. How to solve this? 
My code is here.

```
const getUserExchangeAccountDetails = function(props, params, callback) {
const client = new bittrex(constants.bittrexApiKey, constants.bittrexSecretKey);
let responseArray = [];
let tempArr = [];
let otherArr = [];
let coinNumber = 0;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.getbalances(function (err, response, taskcallback) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            let coinsList = response.result;
            console.log("Results-----", response.result);

            for(let i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++ ){
                let coin = {
                        currency : "",
                        balance : 0,
                        usdPrice : 0,
                        coinsInUsd : [],
                        totalCoins : 0,
                };

                if(response.result[i].Currency != null || 
                    response.result[i].Currency != ""){
                        coin.currency = response.result[i].Currency;
                }

                if(response.result[i].Balance > 0 ){
                    coin.balance = response.result[i].Balance;
                }

                if(coin.currency != "" && coin.balance > 0){
                        coinNumber = coinNumber + 1;
                        coin.totalCoins = coinNumber;
                        if (coin.currency != 'BTCP') {
                            currenciesService.getCurrencyLatestInfo(coin.currency).then((data) => {
                                coin.usdPrice = data;
                                let usdData = conversionIntoDollar.coinsConversionInUsd(coin.balance, coin.usdPrice);
                                coin.coinsInUsd.push(usdData);
                            });
                        }
                        responseArray.push(coin);
                        console.log(responseArray);

                }
            }
            resolve(responseArray);  
        } //else
    });
})
```

}

Here is output of my code, values returning form promises are empty, rest of the properties are working fine.

[Output Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdOcD.png)

Comment: where is `responseArray` coming from ?  where do you `resolve` the promise ? it look like you are not implementing the promise correctly...

Comment: I have updated the code can you please check again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're not waiting for the `currenciesService.getCurrencyLatestInfo` results

Comment: @Bergi So, how to solve this can you please explain?

Comment: Call `resolve` immediately with `response`, put all your code in a `then` callback, and use `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you but it is giving only one object while I've total of 13. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @SharjeelMalik Please update the code in your question with your attempt